# Is this an error to have 'a' as the input for this arrow function?

Tags: javascript, scope, this, arrow-functions

From **You don't know JS - this & Object prototypes**, by Kyle Simpson, page 32, heading **Lexical this**:

```
function foo() {
    return (a) => {
        console.log(this.a);
    };
}

var obj1 = {
    a:2
}

var obj2 = {
    a:3
}

var bar = foo.call(obj1);
bar.call(obj2); // 2, not 3!
```

The point here is that this returned arrow function will inherit the lexical *this* from function *foo*.

What I do not understand is why the input for this arrow function above is `a`?

- I removed the 'a' from the arrow function and this example still works as expected.
- When the arrow function is called via references, they are called with no input arguments.

What is the point of having 'a' as the input to the arrow function?

Comment: You're right, you might want to file an issue.

Comment: I have reported it to O'Reilly Errata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the point of having 'a' as the input to the arrow function?

As you said, it is a variable declaration that is never used.

It is pointless.

ESLint reports:

> 'a' is defined but never used. (no-unused-vars)

Comment: @YuZhang — Perfectly.

Comment: @YuZhang for your second question, you can even simply calls `bar()`

Comment: aha, I see, Lint reports it. Thanks

Comment: @appleapple — Since the purpose of the exercise is to show how arrow functions aren't affected by functions which explicitly change `this`, that would defeat the object.

Comment: @Quentin Good Point.

Comment: I think it'd be easier if it simply `console.log(this)` and try to rebind, though.

Comment: @appleapple, I assumed the author was trying to avoid use the window object as this. Using two custom objects is less abstract.

Comment: @YuZhang Although, yes, my initial thought was the window object, but it can also simply replace `console.log(this.a)` with `console.log(this)`. and imho it'd easier to understand. yomv.